# Websites on the same server communicating

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

I want to separate out the API calls my site makes to another install as the site has become big and buggy by having everything together. I would like to know what ways are there if any to make two sites communicate when they are on the same server.

I originally was thinking I could get the client-facing site to just include the models from the API site through a custom loader for CodeIgniter, but I am currently leaning towards wanting the API site to take advantage of Laravel which would obviously scrap directly loading them.

Currently I have some calls which are using CURL to POST requests, is this the only way? I was hoping to drop the HTTP calls in favour of something more direct.

Comment: can you define too big and buggy? generally its just the code that needs refactoring when the code base becomes too big. But if you have lots of bugs, seperating the code into 2 different instance will not help and will make it a bit harder to debug in the future.

Comment: It is 6 websites (main + 5 subdomains) with all but 1 in active development. Buggy is a comment on Doctrine, it isn't playing nice right now.

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer here as I am far from being an expert in process communication, but if you have some control of the filesystem, you could use named pipes to communicate between the two sites to save on the hTTP requests. I think you can do this by using the [posix_mkfifo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php) function and then simple fopen-type functions (and/or streams). That said, you may find that there's a lot less upset to your code to stick with the HTTP stuff.

Comment: I would have a look at http://jenssegers.be/projects/codeigniter-hmvc-modules which is for seperating the code into modules.

Comment: @mic we already do that.

Comment: @alexrussell I just don't want to introduce any more latency than I have to. I was thinking, would having the server in /etc/hosts as 127.0.0.1 mean the requests between the sites never leave the server itself?

Comment: @mic the problem is that Doctrine does funny things even if you don't touch the database code. Something to do with its Proxies, I think.

Comment: @BeaverusIV as I understand it yes you can use a local connection to save on network latency. However, you still get the (pretty darn minimal) overhead of HTTP headers, etc. But yeah if it's the network hit rather than the HTTP protocol itself that's your issue then that should work. As I understand it, if the server's hostname has been set properly, then there should already be an entry in `/etc/hosts`, but if you use a different host for your site to the server's innate hostname then yeah and entry for `127.0.0.1` should do you.

Comment: @alexrussell if you write up an answer I will accept if no one has anything else to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments to the question, I'm definitely no expert on this kind of stuff, but my original thinking was that IPC-style stuff could be done, maybe using names pipes.

PHP does allow for this in its POSIX and process control functions. Simply use [`posix_mkfifo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php) to create a named pipe and then you should be able to use `fopen`, `fread`, etc. (along with the `stream_*` functions if you need to) to write to and read form the pipe. However, I'm not sure how well that works with a single writer and multiple readers, and it's also probably quite a large change to your code to replace the HTTP stuff you currently have.

So the next possibility is that, if you want to stick with HTTP (and don't mind the small overhead of forming HTTP requests and the headers, etc.), then you should ensure that your server is using local sockets to cut down on transport costs. If your web site's domain name is the same hostname as the server itself this should already be happening (as your `/etc/hosts` file will have any entry pointing the hostname to `127.0.0.1`). However, if not, all you need to do is add such an entry and, as far as I'm aware, it'll work. At the very worst you could hardcode `127.0.0.1` in your code (and ensure your webserver responds correctly to these requests), of course.